# Method taking Collection<Studs> as an argument and returning Collection<Studs> where all elements are unique by "id" and value > 50

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a task to create a method that takes Collection as an argument and returning Collection where all elements are unique by "id" and value > 50

I already have my answers but I have no idea if I'm doing it correctly. Can also someone help me how to do this "where all elements are unique by "id" and value > 50"

Here's my console app program:

```
namespace MyTesting
{
    class Studs
    {
        int id;
        int value;
    }

    class Program
    {
        public ICollection<Studs> GetElements(ICollection<Studs> elements)
        {
            return elements;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just returning the elements you got, so you obviously don't do what you're asked....

Comment: Have a look at [`Enumerable.Distinct()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (look at the sample code there). You might want to use `.ToList()` to turn the result back into an `ICollection`, or maybe you can change `GetElements()` to return `IEnumerable<Studs>` instead.

Comment: *returning collection where all elements are unique by id* - isn't the `id` unique in the original collection?

Comment: What shall happen with *not unique* entries? Keep first? Keep last? Check if they are simply dupes and keep one of them? Keep none of them?

Comment: The instruction also says, "In case of ambiguity, put in target collection any of input elements." I don't get it exactly

Comment: I guess in that case using "distinct" would be ok.

Comment: Actually given your amended requirement, it sounds like `GroupBy()` is going to be the answer.

Comment: Oh I understand. @MatthewWatson I believe groupby is suitable than distinct right? :)

Comment: Yes, correct, because it will do what you want already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the uniqueness, do a GroupBy on the ID, then select whichever element you want from the grouping (e.g.  the first one in this case).

If you like ugly one-liners...

```
ICollection<Studs> GetElements(ICollection<Studs> elements)
{
    return elements.Where(e => e.value > 50).GroupBy(e => e.id).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: And what does this mean? "In case of ambiguity, put in target collection any of input elements."

Comment: It means that if you have multiple values of the same ID both with values over 50, you can pick any of them (i.e.  You don't have to pick the largest or anything).

Comment: `And what does this mean? "In case of ambiguity, put in target collection any of input elements." ` - It means that you have omitted part of the requirement from your question.

Comment: return elements.Where(e => e.value > 50).GroupBy(e => e.id).Select(g => g.First()).ToList(); does this already solve the issues? @MatthewWatson

Comment: It does.  It just selects the first element, which satisfies the "any of input elements" option.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mitch :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely eliminate items having duplicates you can do this :

```
        public ICollection<Studs> GetElements(ICollection<Studs> elements)
        {
            var ret = from e in elements
                where elements.All(x => x.id != e.id || x == e) && e.value > 50
                select e;
            return ret.ToList();
        }
```

if you want to return the first occurrence for each id, you can do this :

```
        public ICollection<Studs> GetElements(ICollection<Studs> elements)
        {
            var ret = from e in elements
                where e.value > 50
                group e by e.id
                into g
                select g.FirstOrDefault();
            return ret.ToList();
        }
```

Comment: And what does this mean? "In case of ambiguity, put in target collection any of input elements."

Comment: so the second one is fine.
In case of ambiguity, it takes the first element > 50